# C++ Templates - LinkedList

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

EDIT -- Answered below, missed the angled braces. Thanks all.

I have been attempting to write a rudimentary singly linked list, which I can use in other programs. I wish it to be able to work with built-in and user defined types, meaning it must be templated.

Due to this my node must also be templated, as I do not know the information it is going to store. I have written a node class as follows -

```
template <class T> class Node
{
    T data; //the object information
    Node* next; //pointer to the next node element

public:
    //Methods omitted for brevity
};
```

My linked list class is implemented in a seperate class, and needs to instantiate a node when adding new nodes to the end of the list. I have implemented this as follows -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T> class CustomLinkedList
{
    Node<T> *head, *tail;

public:

    CustomLinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    ~CustomLinkedList()
    {

    }

    //Method adds info to the end of the list
    void add(T info)
    {
        if(head == NULL) //if our list is currently empty
        {
            head = new Node<T>; //Create new node of type T
            head->setData(info);
            tail = head;
        }
        else //if not empty add to the end and move the tail
        {
            Node* temp = new Node<T>;
            temp->setData(info);
            temp->setNextNull();
            tail->setNext(temp);
            tail = tail->getNext();
        }
    }

    //print method omitted
};
```

I have set up a driver/test class as follows -

```
#include "CustomLinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CustomLinkedList<int> firstList;

    firstList.add(32);
    firstList.printlist();
    //Pause the program until input is received
    int i;
    cin >> i;

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error upon compilation however - **error C2955: 'Node' : use of class template requires template argument list** - which points me to the following line of code in my add method -

```
Node* temp = new Node<T>;
```

I do not understand why this has no information about the type, since it was passed to linked list when created in my driver class. **What should I be doing to pass the type information to Node?**

Should I create a private node struct instead of a seperate class, and combine the methods of both classes in one file? I'm not certain this would overcome the problem, but I think it might. I would rather have seperate classes if possible though.

Thanks, Andrew.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response all. Silly mistake on my part. Cheers.

Comment: Did you know the C++ standard library already provides a doubly-linked list template (std::list)? Also, the Boost library provides "intrusive" linked lists.

Comment: Yes I know that, but making your own is supposed to be good practice, especially for pointer logic. Plus I want to implement some of the methods a little differently. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Might wanna try

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
```

Also, to get hints on how to design the list, you can of course look at std::list, although it can be a bit daunting at times.

Comment: Yeah at the moment I am looking at some methods for it. Most I don't need though, which is nice since I don't have the experience to implement some methods yet. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 17):

While the answers have already been provided, I think I'll add my grain of salt.

When designing templates class, it is a good idea not to repeat the template arguments just about everywhere, just in case you wish to (one day) change a particular detail. In general, this is done by using typedefs.

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
  // bunch of types
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef T& reference_type;
  typedef T const& const_reference_type;
  typedef T* pointer_type;
  typedef T const* const_pointer_type;

  // From now on, T should never appear
private:
  value_type m_value;
  Node* m_next;
};


template <class T>
class List
{
  // private, no need to expose implementation
  typedef Node<T> node_type;

  // From now on, T should never appear
  typedef node_type* node_pointer;

public:
  typedef typename node_type::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename node_type::reference_type reference_type;
  typedef typename node_type::const_reference_type const_reference_type;
  // ...

  void add(value_type info);

private:
  node_pointer m_head, m_tail;
};
```

It is also better to define the methods outside of the class declaration, makes it is easier to read the interface.

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::add(value_type info)
{
  if(head == NULL) //if our list is currently empty
  {
    head = new node_type;
    head->setData(info);
    tail = head;
  }
  else //if not empty add to the end and move the tail
  {
    Node* temp = new node_type;
    temp->setData(info);
    temp->setNextNull();
    tail->setNext(temp);
    tail = tail->getNext();
  }
}
```

Now, a couple of remarks:

- it would be more user friendly if `List<T>::add` was returning an iterator to the newly added objects, like `insert` methods do in the STL (and you could rename it insert too)
- in the implementation of `List<T>::add` you assign memory to `temp` then perform a bunch of operations, if any throws, you have leaked memory
- the `setNextNull` call should not be necessary: the constructor of `Node` should initialize all the data member to meaningfull values, included `m_next`

So here is a revised version:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(value_type info): m_value(info), m_next(NULL) {}

template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator insert(value_type info)
{
  if (m_head == NULL)
  {
    m_head = new node_type(info);
    m_tail = m_head;
    return iterator(m_tail);
  }
  else
  {
    m_tail.setNext(new node_type(info));
    node_pointer temp = m_tail;
    m_tail = temp.getNext();
    return iterator(temp);
  }
}
```

Note how the simple fact of using a proper constructor improves our exception safety: if ever anything throw during the constructor, `new` is required not to allocate any memory, thus nothing is leaked and we have not performed any operation yet. Our `List<T>::insert` method is now resilient.

Final question:

Usual `insert` methods of single linked lists insert at the beginning, because it's easier:

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::iterator insert(value_type info)
{
  m_head = new node_type(info, m_head); // if this throws, m_head is left unmodified
  return iterator(m_head);
}
```

Are you sure you want to go with an insert at the end ? or did you do it this way because of the `push_back` method on traditional vectors and lists ?

Comment: SetNextNull always struck me as the sort of thing that would lead to leaks. I prefer a StealList() method that sets next to NULL and returns whatever was there out the LHS. It is also useful in atomic linked lists at times when you would like to go take the list off into a corner out of public view for a while to monkey with it and bring it back later. This then  lets you add assert(NULL == this->next) to SetNext() to help detect misuse.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;
```

Might be worth a `typedef NodeType = Node<T>` in the `CustomLinkedList` class to prevent this problem from cropping up again.

Comment: I skipped the typedefs in my book. I'll go back and look at it thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

That line should read

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
```

Same for the `next` pointer in the Node class.

Comment: Well spotted, I completely missed the self reference. Thanks.

Comment: "Same for the next pointer in the Node class" that's not needed. at least for me, it gives a error if I do that.

Answer (score 1):

As said, the solution is

```
Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
```

... because `Node` itself is not a type, `Node<T>` is.

Answer (score 0):

And you will need to specify the template parameter for the Node *temp in printlist also.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed it now - I think I'll just edit it out of my post as it isn't relevant to the question really, and wastes space.

Answer (score 0):

```
// file: main.cc

#include "linkedlist.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LinkedList<int> list;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) list.add(i);
    list.print();
}

// file: node.h

#ifndef _NODE_H
#define _NODE_H

template<typename T> class LinkedList;
template<typename T>class Node {
    friend class LinkedList<T>;
    public:
        Node(T data = 0, Node<T> *next = 0)
            : data(data), next(next)
        { /* vacio */ }
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T> *next;
};

#endif//_NODE_H

// file: linkedlist.h

#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "node.h"

template<typename T> class LinkedList {
    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();
        void add(T);
        void print();
    private:
        Node<T> *head;
        Node<T> *tail;
};

#endif//_LINKEDLIST_H

template<typename T>LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
    : head(0), tail(0)
{ /* empty */ }

template<typename T>LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    if(head) {
        Node<T> *p = head;
        Node<T> *q = 0;

        while(p) {
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete q;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>LinkedList<T>::void add(T info) {
    if(head) {
        tail->next = new Node<T>(info);
        tail = tail->next;
    } else {
        head = tail = new Node<T>(info);
    }
}

template<typename T>LinkedList<T>::void print() {
    if(head) {
        Node<T> *p = head;

        while(p) {
            cout << p->data << "-> ";
            p = p->next;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should add new node in this way

> `Node<T>* temp=new node<T>;`

Hope you Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template < class data > class node {
    private :
        data t;
        node<data > *ptr;
    public:
    node() {
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    data get_data() {
        return t;
    }
    void set_data(data d) {
        t = d;
    }
    void set_ptr(node<data > *p) {
        ptr = p;
    }
    node * get_ptr() {
        return ptr;
    }
};
template <class data > node < data > * add_at_last(data  d  , node<data > *start) {
    node< data > *temp , *p  = start;
    temp = new node<data>();
    temp->set_data(d);
    temp->set_ptr(NULL);
    if(!start) {
        start = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        while(p->get_ptr()) {
            p = p->get_ptr();
        }
        p->set_ptr(temp);
    }
}
template < class data > void display(node< data > *start) {
    node< data > *temp;
    temp = start;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        cout<<temp->get_data()<<" ";
        temp = temp->get_ptr();
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
template <class data > node < data > * reverse_list(node<data > * start) {
    node< data > *p = start , *q = NULL , *r = NULL;
    while(p->get_ptr()) {
        q = p;
        p = p->get_ptr();
        q->set_ptr(r);
        r = q;
    }
    p->set_ptr(r);
    return p;
}
int main() {
    node < int > *start;
    for(int i =0 ; i < 10 ; i ++) {
        if(!i) {
            start = add_at_last(i , start);
        }
        else {
            add_at_last(i , start);
        }
    }
    display(start);
    start = reverse_list(start);
    cout<<endl<<"reverse list is"<<endl<<endl;
    display(start);
}
```