# What are the implications of performing a shallow copy on an array in order to resize it?

Tags: c#, deep-copy, shallow-copy

If my understanding of deep and shallow copying is correct my question is an impossible one.
If you have an array (a[10]) and perform a shallow copy (b[20]) wouldn't this be impossible as the data in b wouldn't be contiguous?

If i've got this completely wrong could someone advise a fast way to immitate (in c#) c++'s ability to do a realloc in order to resize an array.

**NOTE**
Im looking at the .Clone() and .Copy() members of the System.Array object.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392397/arrays-whats-the-point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't resize an existing array, however, you can use:

```
Array.Resize(ref arr, newSize);
```

This allocates a new array, copies the data from the old array into the new array, and updates the `arr` variable (which is passed by-ref in this case). Is that what you mean?

However, any *other* references still pointing at the old array will not be updated. A better option might be to work with `List<T>` - then you don't need to resize it manually, and you don't have the issue of out-of-date references. You just `Add`/`Remove` etc. Generally, you don't tend to use arrays directly very often. They have their uses, but they aren't the default case.

---

Re your comments;

- boxing: `List<T>` doesn't box. That is one of the points about generics; under the hood, `List<T>` is a wrapper around `T[]`, so a `List<int>` has an `int[]` - no boxing. The older `ArrayList` is a wrapper around `object[]`, so that *does* box; of course, boxing [isn't as bad as you might assume](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx) anyway.
- workings of `Array.Resize`; <s>if I recall, it finds the size of `T`, then uses `Buffer.BlockCopy` to blit the contents</s> the actual details are hidden by an internal call - but essentially after allocating a new array it is a blit (memcpy) of the data between the two arrays, so it should be pretty quick; note that for reference-types this only copies the reference, not the object on the heap. However, if you are resizing regularly, `List<T>` would usually be a lot simpler (and quicker unless you basically re-implement what `List<T>` does re spare capacity to minimise the number of resizes).

Comment: Some valid points, but i am specifically looking at arrays. I don't want the overhead incurred from objects that box arrays such as lists.
Do you have any details on the inner workings of the Array.Resize method? ie is it very fast?